# Repeat invalid user input until it is valid (pseudo)

Tags: javascript, loops, input

For some reason I'm having hard time executing the following code for my game in JS:

Let's say we ask users to move a piece on the board. The positions that they can make is either position A, position B or position C. Each position can only hold one piece at a time. Otherwise it is invalid move.

The first user decides to move position A. The second user wants to move to position A but of course, it can't because it is already taken. Until the second user correctly inputs a valid move, the first user has to wait till then.

In my code, I was able to create a function that checks if the user's input is valid or not , board.validMove(position) (boolean).

I would've thought something like this works but it seems to go an infinite loop:

```
Game.prototype.playerTurn = function(player){
    $(".cell").click(function(){
        var position = #(this).attr("id");
        var isItValid = board.validMove(position) // this will return true or false if it is valid
        while( isItValid === false) { // I'd thought until isItValid becomes true, it will ask the user to choose another position
            game.playerTurn(player) //call again
            if (isItValid === true){
                break;
            }
        }
        board.updateBoard(position, player) // updates the board
        game.switchPlayer() //switch the currentPlayer
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: WHat does `game.playerTurn()` do. How does `isItValid` get changed?

Comment: It looks like you're setting up a new click handler every time you call `playerTurn`. Are you sure that's what you want to do? Also, with that `while` loop, you never give the player a chance to change their move. Instead, you should check if it's valid and if it isn't, indicate that the move is invalid and exit the function early. Otherwise, perform the rest of the logic for that turn.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea here is that when you use a `while` loop, the user never has a chance to change anything. As long as JavaScript is *actively* running, it can't accept any input from the user.

Instead, you want to verify if the move is valid and only proceed if it is. Otherwise, you want to inform the user that what they did was invalid.

Here's a basic example of that idea:

```js
// Track which players turn it is
var whosTurn = 1;

// Only setup the event handler once 
// Setting up the handler multiple times will cause problems
$('div').click(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  var playerClass = 'player-' + whosTurn;
  if ($el.hasClass('taken')) {
    // Alert the user that it isn't a valid move and allow them to change their move
    alert('That spot is already taken');
    return;
  }

  // Mark the spot and switch the players
  $el.addClass('taken ' + playerClass);
  whosTurn = (whosTurn === 1) ? 2 : 1;
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #333;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.player-1 {
  background-color: #F00;
}
.player-2 {
  background-color: #0F0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div style="clear: left">4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! That was really helpful.
I didnt realize I was setting the handler event everytime the function was calling. 
cheers!

Answer (score 1):

variable `isItValid` is defined inside the function and I don't see any code modifying it. I assume you wanted `game.playerTurn(player)` to modify it, but it can't. You'll need to check if the move is valid in every iteration of your `while` loop. Also remove

```
if (isItValid === true){
                break;
}
```

It is fairly redundant.

Also `.click` does not wait for a click, it attaches a click handler. Here is an example of how you can attach one handler and toggle it's usability

```
(function($) {
  // Flags
  var waitingForClick = flase;

  // Some action sets waitingForClick = true

  // Click handlers
  $('.cell').click(function(
    if(!waitingForClick) return;

    movePlayer(this);
  });

  function movePlayer(cell) {
    var position = $(cell).attr("id");
  }
})(jQuery);
```